# Do Java generics allow for memory savings in arrays of primitives such as short?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I've done a bit of Googling, but I've been unable to find a decisive answer to this question. For clarification, consider a class like this:

```
public class MyContainer<T> {
    private T[] _store;
    private int _size;
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the memory savings one would get by using an array of type `short` vs. `int`, despite the fact that a variable with a reference to `MyContainer` must be declared with primitive wrapper classes like `Short` and `Integer`, and instances of `MyContainer` must be created with those same wrapper classes?

In my searches I found that the Java compiler applies [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) to generics, but I'm not so sure that I can now assume Java does not have some sort of optimization for generically-typed arrays.

Does anyone have evidence for or against this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of this should matter.  It's a micro-optimization that's unlikely to make a measurable difference in real code.

Comment: duffymo is absolutely right. Don't worry about this unless you've conclusively determined, through extensive testing, that it is the source of some sort of bottleneck (unlikely).

Comment: Don't use Integer[] or Short[] if you can. You are much better off having int[] if you need to support both types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics themselves don't offer any memory saving, and Integer/Short are larger than the primitive equivalent.

Using Integer.valueOf( int) or Short.valueOf( short), or just plain auto-boxing, will however re-use shared instances for common small positive & negative numbers. So that can save memory over instantiating each value separately.

See:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)

Generics are an *object reference* type, and will thus tend to be somewhat larger/slower than an array of primitive `int` or `short`. Java applies no space or time optimizations to a generic collection such as `List<Integer>` compared to other Lists, since internally the JVM shares the same class & bytecode between all `List` instances. This is true of arrays also.

Don't worry about memory or performance, unless this is core code to be used near the bottom of a performance-critical stack. Only the deepest-looped, heavily-used & most performance-constrained code sections should be candidates for design-stage optimization.

Answer (score 2):

No. Generics have nothing to do with *either* primitives *or* memory saving.

Comment: +1 generics improve compile time type checking and nothing more by design.  Ie it is designed to have no impact at runtime to ensure backward compatability.

Comment: @PaulBellora Thanks, but they never do. I just treat it as site vandalism.

Comment: Perhaps it was downvoted because it was a vague answer with no explanation. @PeterLawrey's comment explained thoroughly enough that there was no need to request further clarification.

Comment: @blue_deref Perhaps that's what they *thought:* it's anybody's guess. I'm not interested in speculation. But there is nothing 'vague' about 'no', and the sentence that follows *is* an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to achieve the memory savings one would get by using an array of type `short` vs. `int`, despite the fact that a variable with a reference to `MyContainer` must be declared with primitive wrapper classes like `Short` and `Integer`, and instances of `MyContainer` must be created with those same wrapper classes?

Just to build on the existing answers, it *is* possible to implement a generic collection interface with a backing primitive array, but not *generically*. For example [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Ints.asList(int...)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList%28int...%29) returns a `List<Integer>` implementation that's backed by an `int[]` and simply boxes/unboxes on all its method calls. But Guava has separate implementations of that pattern for each primitive - there's no way to unify it like you're hoping to do.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use

```
    TIntArrayList.wrap(int[] array)
```

from the `Trove4j` library which wraps your array into [Trove](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.trove4j/trove4j)'s collection allowing you to save memory and add standard Java's `ArrayList` features like auto-expanding, sorting, selecting, iterating etc.

And to for compliance with Java collections (List), you use the decorator

```
    new TIntListDecorator(TIntList list)
```